# Laravel AJAX Post Referencing ID on Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This has to be a basic issue. I have a post request to delete a record from a database table, but it's not deleting. It's because in my AJAX request and URL, I reference the ID of the record in the table, but the controller method does not associate this variable with the ID column.

JS:

$notificationId is the rendered ID of that record in the DB table.

```
$('.remove-notification').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $userUsername = $('.user-username').text();
    $notificationId = $(this).parent().siblings('.notification-id').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/"+$userUsername+"/notifications/delete/"+$notificationId,
        error: function(data){
            /*Retrieve errors and append any error messages.*/
            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            console.log(errors);
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function postDeleteNotification(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        DB::table('notifications_user')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->delete();
    }
}
```

The request processes without any error, the URL of the request looks good in the console. If I remove the "->where('id', $id)" then the basic delete method works, so I know it's an issue with that where statement. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
Route::post('/{username}/notifications/confirm', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController@postConfirmNotifications',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::post('/{username}/notifications/delete/{notificationId}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController@postDeleteNotification',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);

Route::post('/{username}/notifications/all/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController@postDeleteNotificationAll',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Comment: die and dump the sql query and let's check what you get!

Comment: How do I do that with an AJAX request?

Comment: You just need to put `DB::enableQuerylog()` before query and after `dd( DB::getQuerylog() )`;

Comment: I dont think you can do Auth::user in ajax request

Comment: Auth::user does work because if I remove the 2nd where clause, it works fine.

Comment: @geckob nop that works fine whatever request it is!

Comment: show us the routes file, i think the id is not passed correctly, try to put a number associated with the athenticated user(instead of a variable) and if it works, what i said would be correct

Comment: Updated w/ routes file. Middle one is what we're dealing with. The other 2 are for other methods of similar functionality. Also, using query builder for this, not Eloquent so detach won't work. Thanks!

Comment: your routes says/{notificationId} and in the methos u hv {id}, i think that should be {notificationId} right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I changed it after. Still didn't make a difference.

Comment: I return a json request and all it show in the console is "Object {8: " "}" where 8 is the id being passed through.

Comment: try to put a number instead of $id in where() (it should be a valid one , i mean i should exist in database for the auth user) and check if it works

Comment: Yep, hardcoding in the number works just fine

Comment: why you need this `{username}` in the beginning of the route when it's not being used in the method..! That might be the issue

Comment: That's it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out that your method should look like something

```
public function postDeleteNotification(Request $request,$username, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        DB::table('notifications_user')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->delete();
    }
}
```